# when i am using react-native-maps it gives me this error

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-maps

I have install react-native-maps as globally
when i am using react-native link react-native-maps it gives me this error anyone can help me to fix this issue i am using node version 6.14.4
npm version 6.4.1

this is ther error

> ```
> /home/yasiru/easybooking/project/Yasi/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/checkNodeVersion.js:43
>     );
>     ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
>     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
>     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
>     at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yasiru/easybooking/project/Yasi/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:17:1)
> ```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review the [ask] section and [edit] your question in order to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

6.14.4 is the latest version of the 6.x LTS release of Node JS, and there is a bug in react-native that affects older runtimes: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/e61176d650e2b5fe51dd6cd4c429ff47a1a9b1dc. Based on the detail in your question this looks like the issue you are experiencing.

If you're on v0.56.0 of React Native (which has this bug with old runtimes) then you will either need to upgrade to one of the v0.57.0 release candidates with `npm install react-native@0.57.0-rc.4` or upgrade your version of Node JS to a later release.